# replace an SSD disk in RAID5 with bigger one

Tags: debian, mdadm, software-raid, raid5

Some years ago I created a RAID5 array with `mdadm`. It consists of 3 1TB SSD (*Samsung SSD 860*). Here is how I created it:

```
mdadm -E /dev/sd[a-c]
fdisk /dev/sda
fdisk /dev/sdb
fdisk /dev/sdc
mdadm -C /dev/md0 -l 5 -n 3 /dev/sd[a-c]1
watch -n1 cat /proc/mdstat
mdadm --detail /dev/md0
mdadm --detail --scan --verbose >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

Today I got, for the second time this week, an error from `smartd` that indicates that a disk is dying (`Offline uncorrectable sectors` and `Currently unreadable (pending) sectors`). The best option is to replace the disk.

Now I have 2 options. I buy a new 1TB SSD or I buy a bigger one (2T *SAMSUNG 870 QVO*?) since they have become cheaper. The advantage of the last option is that after I replace the last of the 3 1TB SSD disks I would be able to double my RAID5 array.

I searched if it was easy and simple to do. I found out that both 'possible' and 'not possible' is mentioned. Perhaps it was once not possible and now it is or it might be dependent on the software/method used.

Comment: It should be possible.  If i were you, even if you get a new 2TB SSD, I'd make the partition the same size as the existing partitions.  it will be **much** safer to entirely separate the replacement operation from any future size increase operation.   Later, you can replace the other two drives (again, with the same partition size) and when they've all been replaced, you can increase the size of each partition and grow the fs on the array.   As always, **make a backup before doing anything dangerous.**